# SaveAs Cell Value From One Sheet Within Excel Book With Multiple Sheets

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am trying to SaveAs in Excel 2010 VBA. The Excel file has 8 sheets and I think this is why I cannot save as a cell value easily. It is like the code cannot find "K2" (See comment below where code fails). Run time error 1004.

```
Sub RecFilter()
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$H$159").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=Array( _
    "(1)", "(112)", "(113)", "(126)", "(14)", "(144)", "(216)", "(3,274)", "(448)", "(468)", _
    "(5)", "(65)", "(72)", "(80)", "(900)", "(960)", "106", "14", "2", "2,880", "3,420", "504" _
    , "513", "56", "665", "72", "845", "9,814", "900"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveSheet.Columns("A:H").EntireColumn.AutoFit
ActiveSheet.Rows("1:2").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
ActiveSheet.Range("J1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Start Date"
ActiveSheet.Range("J2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "End Date"
ActiveSheet.Range("K1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1/1/2000"
ActiveSheet.Range("K2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1/7/2000"
ActiveSheet.Columns("K:K").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim Path As String
Dim filename As String
Path = "C:\Users\TEST\Desktop\"

'THIS IS WHERE IS FAILS
filename =  ActiveSheet.Range("K2")

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=Path & filename & ".xlsx", 
FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to pass `filename = ActiveSheet.Range("K2").Value` to the `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:` where `Range("K2").Value` contains forward slash characters which cannot be included in a saved file name.
`ActiveSheet.Range("K2").Select`
`ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1/7/2000"`

`C:\Users\TEST\Desktop\1/7/2000.xlsx` is not a valid filename.

Try changing `Range("K2").Value` to a hyphenated date data type.

Answer (score 1):

K2 contains characters that are invalid for a filename.
Try replacing the \ signs by something else. For example an underscore (_).

You can replace it in K2 itself, but that will break the usefulness of it as a date.

a better option is to replace it only for the filename.

Use this line:

```
Filename = Replace(ActiveSheet.Range("K2"), "/", "_")
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
filename =  ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 11).Value
```

Comment: Edited now.  Cells(2,11) is the same as K2